# Growth of $\pi(n+r_{0}(n))-\pi(n-r_{0}(n))$ with $r_{0}(n)=\inf\{r\ge 0, (n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$

Tags: number-theory

Assuming Goldbach's conjecture, let's denote by $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r≥0,(n−r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$ and by $k_{0}(n)$ the quantity $\pi(n+r_{0}(n))−\pi(n−r_{0}(n))$.

It seems (see ideasfornumbertheory.com) that $r_{0}(n)\ll\log^{4}n$
and Cramer's conjecture boils down to saying that $2\dfrac{r_{0}(n)}{k_{0}(n)}<\log^{2} n$ for $n$ large enough, while $r_{0}(n)$ is on average roughly equal to $\log^{2}(n)$ and twin prime conjecture implies that $\liminf r_{0}(n)=1$ as long as $n$ is composite. Thus one should be able to write: $r_{0}(n)=\log^{O(1)}n$.

As the quantity $\dfrac{2r_{0}(n)}{k_{0}(n)}$ should be on average roughly equal to $\log n$ from the PNT, one can expect the relation $k_{0}(n)\ll_{\varepsilon}r_{0}(n)^{1/2+\varepsilon}$ to hold.

Another way to derive this heuristically is to consider that the primes have density $1/\log n$ among the integers of the size of $n$, hence the gauss integers in the square built on the interval $(n-r_{0}(n), n+r_{0}(n))$ having both real and imaginary parts equal to primes have density $1/\log^{2}n$. As $\log^{2}n$ is on average the order of magnitude of $r_{0}(n)$ one can write the approximate equality $\left(\dfrac{k_{0}(n)}{r_{0}(n)}\right)^{2}\approx \frac{1}{r_{0}(n)}$, giving $k_{0}(n)^{2}\approx r_{0}(n)$ and thus $k_{0}(n)\approx r_{0}(n)^{1/2}$.

My question is: does the conjectured inequality follow from the assumption of both GRH and Goldbach's conjecture?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you know for a fixed $n$ ($ \ge 4$ ?) there is always a couple of primes $n+r,n-r$ ?

Comment: As I said, one needs to assume Goldbach's conjecture: from $2n=p+q$ with both $p$ and $q$ and $p\ge q$ primes, one gets $2r=p-q$.

Comment: don't you think that for any $c > 0$, there is a $B > 0$ such that $\pi(x+\log^c x)-\pi(x) > B \log^c x$ infinitely many times ?

Comment: I don't think so. It would give too big a density of primes in such an interval for infinitely many $c$.

Comment: too big compared to what ? it is clearly true when you replace $\log^c x$ by a constant $A$.

Comment: Measuring such a density by $\delta:=\log(\pi(x+y)-\pi(y))/\log y$ would give $\delta\gt c^{-1}$.

Comment: a density is when you take the mean over $y < N$ or $x < N$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42709/discussion-between-sylvain-julien-and-user1952009).